# Why does the enthalpy of a liquid not vary with pressure?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

A homework question states the enthalpy of a liquid at 0.02bar and 300K and says even though the process in the question occurs at 5 bar and 300K it states that "thermodynamics shows that the enthalpy of a liquid does not vary with pressure". Why is this the case?

The change in enthalpy can be written as $dh=du+v\,dP+P\,dv$ as we can assume $dv=0$ for a liquid this simplifies down to $dh=du+v\,dP$. According to this equation a change in pressure would cause a change in enthalpy even if temperature was to stay constant.

Edit: I assume the above expression can be further simplified as $du=0$ when the temperature between the two pressures is the same so this implies there should be a change in enthalpy between the two pressures by $dh=v\,dp$.

Can we just assume that enthalpy is the same because the $v\,dP$ term is very small or is there another explanation? If the former, why is this the case?

Comment: No, the thermodynamics is deeper than that. Any good textbook should have a section where they introduce the enthalpy and write it as $H(S,p)$. One arrives at $\delta H / \delta p = V$ at constant $S$. So, it holds true for a non-compressive liquid.

Comment: Oh dear, I just realised I almost came to the same conclusion above. I'm assuming my working to get to the point that $dh=v\,dp$ are correct? Actually, doesn't this mean enthalpy varies by a constant factor as pressure increases, ie enthalpy is not constant with pressure?

Comment: The enthalpy is relatively insensitive to pressure because the specific volume of a liquid is so very much smaller than the specific volume of a gas.   So $v\Delta p$ is very small, unless the pressure change is huge.  If you have a set of steam tables, look up and compare the internal energy of liquid water with the enthalpy of liquid water at different pressures.

Answer (score 2):

**Qualitative answer:**

The properties of matter depend on pressure and temperature. Pressure affects properties because it squeezes molecules closer together, hence stronger interactions. In a liquid molecules are practically as close as they can be. It takes pretty high pressures to change the density in any measurable way. Since moderate pressures don't change the distance between neighboring molecules by much, they don't affect their properties much either. This applies to properties such as density, internal energy, enthalpy, entropy, heat capacity.... Some properties however do depend on pressure rather sensitively. The compressibility factor is one example. So one has to be careful.